# Real time programming with real time module

Tags: arduino-uno

If you install a real time clock like DS3231 Real Time Clock Module RTC Sensor High Precision, can you program digital output (such as turning 12VDC valves on) based on day of week and time?

I mean like turning digital output 5 on Friday at 7am for 10 minutes, for example.

Comment: Yes you can.  You do have to take into account power fails and reboot procedures.

Comment: @RohitGupta Please do not answer in comments. Make an answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a battery powered project where the solution has to be low power ?

Comment: you can program the state of a digital output based on almost any event you can think of, providing that you have a way to detect the event